# Construct PHP method depending on input variable

Tags: php, eloquent

I have an eloquent method which should look like the following code example right now:

```
DB::table('table')
    ->select('id','name','start_time','end_time', ....)
    ->get();
```

Depending on a variable I want to set the ->where() method for different properties.

I have come up with two possible methods which are both *IMHO* suboptimal:

- Construct as string and use eval() --> eval() is bad
- set multiple if clauses and run the upper code depending on the if clause but it would be an enormous amount of code to handle every possible constellation

What I'm looking for is to append the where clause dynamically depending on a if clause, like (pseudocode):

```
$command = DB::table('table')->('id','name','start_time','end_time', ....)

if($request->name){
  $command .= ->where(...)
}

if($request->start_time){
  $command .= ->where(...)
}

$command .= ->get()
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're trying to append a string. Just call the method on the object, like `$command->where(..)`. But yes, its possible. Just try it ;-)

Comment: If you cannot see the wood for the trees... Thank you!